# How to use the filter function to identify the index of special characters

Tags: python

I am trying to use a generator function of sorts (I think I need to use the filter generator) to identify the index location of the special characters in a string (in Python 3.7)

Using "extended" code I can write it as follows

```
string = "4+10*3"
for (index,char) in enumerate(string):
    if char in ["*", "+"]: print (index)
```

I am struggling to get my generator expression to work. This is what I wrote:

```
filter(lambda i: index for (index,char) in enumerate(string) in ["*", "+"], string)
```

I know this is not really a useful thing to be able to do, but I want to see if its possible as I've just learned about the filter function and thought it'd be interesting to see if its possible.

Thanks

Comment: You cannot have a for loop like that @EML. Check my answer below :) And consider accepting the answer if it works for you :_

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a for loop like that in the [lambda](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda). A `lambda` is an anonymous function which returns a value.

A nice `trick` to extract the indexes along with the match is to `zip` the characters and indexes together, and then apply the filter function on the character

```
string = "4+10*3"
indexes = list(range(len(string)))

zip_iter = zip(string, indexes)
#[('4', 0), ('+', 1), ('1', 2), ('0', 3), ('*', 4), ('3', 5)]

#Zip characaters in the string and indexes together, then check if the character lies in the list
print(list(filter(lambda i: i[0] in ["*", "+"], zip_iter)))
```

The output will be

```
[('+', 1), ('*', 4)]
```